# ERC721 Minting Randomness

Tags: erc-721, chainlink, mint, randomness

Trying to figure out how to do the following. I wouldn't need the code, just an understanding of viable methods as I can't locate an answer.

An NFT minting process for 2,000 NFTs. IDs from 0-9 would be 'legendary' NFTs. What I'd like to do, is have each minter try their luck getting an ID from 0-9 first. If it fails, to then mint from the #10-1999 set of tokens.

I was hoping for it to work like this:

1 - get a random number between 0-1999

2 - if it falls between 0-9, I can mint the next available token between 0-9 (if there's any left)

3 - if it doesn't just mint the next available token between 10-1999.

**Chainlink** -
This seems to be a two-call process, so I can't generate the randomness on the fly.

**Pseudo-randomness** -
I've seen the standard random number option, using `keccak256` but I understand this to be predictable for miners?

Can I use Chainlink's `fulfillRandomWords` callback to mint the token, considering I'd generate a random number 2000 times?

Are there any other options available to me?

Answer (score 2):

The best practice you can implement Is to use Chain Link VRF V2 , for creating randomness. It will help you to create pure random numbers. But remember it will cost you link token as gas-fee. Bcz chain link is not free.

Don't use keccak256 for generating randomness because it is predictable.

Watch this video first , so that your concert of creating randomness with Chainlink clear.
https://youtu.be/ndKOnPfFrvQ

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a post using three different alternatives to create vrf numbers (Chainlink/API3 or Witnet). There is also a repo with the demo code.
https://medium.com/coinmonks/schedule-randomness-with-gelato-and-witnet-api3-chainlink-vrf-1ebc0aac37d

Hope it helps!